# how do I Import configurable products into magento

Tags: magento

Im using a CSV file to import some configurable products into magento, I made a configurable product with the options I wanted etc in this case **width**, once i added the configurable product and checked it worked the way I wanted it I downloaded the CSV file to my computer opened it up and located the configurable product and I simply copied the the configurable product and pasted it again so i now have 2 configurable products, I know it wont upload the same thing again so I changed the name, url, urlkey, and everything else so that it was unique but still exactly like the configurable product I copied, but when i tried uploading it, it uploads and imports successfully but when i look at the duplicated product (productB) it says its a simple product rather then a configurable product and I don't know why its not putting it as a configurable.

[image]
any ideas why its ignoring the spreadsheet and imports it as a simple product rather then what the spreadsheet says ?

Comment: Can you provide either the file or the full row of the csv file you're importing?

Comment: ATT99114DAMSON  Width configurable Carpets Default Category base    14/08/14 13:31     Attraction 114 Damson   1 no_selection         Use config Use config Attraction 114 Damson   Product Info Column  0 1 Attraction 114 Damson no_selection     1 4 no_selection  14/08/14 13:32 attraction-114-damson attraction-114-damson-647.html 4   0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1  1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0                      ATT99114DAMSON-2.0M X 4M (6' 6" X 13' 1") width 2.0M X 4M (6' 6" X 13' 1") 2

Comment: thats a full row from the csv file there are several other roads that handle the width options.

Comment: Errr, there are no commas in there! It's hard to read. Can you post actual files showing a header row and data row for the exported file and the file you're importing. That'll make it much easier to see what you're actually doing.

Comment: Here is a link to the file its off one configurable item but when you copy and change the names and try and upload it it doesn't work uploads the products but doesn't change the main product to configurable - https://www.sendspace.com/file/jk32bz

Answer (score 0):

use can use magmi http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

this one of the method of the mass importer of the products

Regarding other details you will get to know on

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

this is just a one method of product upload.

Hope this method of product solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your file it's hard to tell the issue, especially as I use Magmi. However, one thing that's "dangerous" is the use of single and double quotes, they can really confuse things, especially if you're using Excel to create your CSV file. I have a couple of suggestions:

**1. Manually create a simple product and export it**

Create a simple product manually and then export it. That will show you what your file should look like. It's always worked for me.

**2. Create a robust csv file**

I had problems with quotes in fields and I found I had to create a UTF-8 csv file with proper handling of quotes. I do this by using OpenOffice. Unfortunately Excel does not give you the facilities.